# theoretical confidence interval depending on sample size

Tags: r, sampling, sample-size, central-limit-theorem, uncertainty

I am using R and plain English to express my question. Let us say I have a "true"/made up population, which is normally distributed with a mean of 500000 and a standard deviation of 13000:

```
mean <- 500000
sd <- 13000
population <- rnorm(10000000, mean=mean, sd=sd)
```

I can then repeatedly sample from this population using different samples sizes ranging from 3 to 150. For each sample, I also calculate the 95% confidence interval using a t distribution. I think this is safe as at the beginning my sample size is pretty low (i.e. 3). This is not really exploited here but I think this would be correct?

```
results <- NULL

for (sample_size_ in 3:150) {
    
    for (sample_number_ in 1:10) {
        
        sample_ <- sample(population, sample_size_)
        ci_test <- t.test(sample_, conf.level=0.95)

        df <- data.frame(
            sample_size = sample_size_
            , low_ci = ci_test$conf.int[[1]] 
            , up_ci = ci_test$conf.int[[2]]
            , mean = mean(sample_)
        )

        results <- rbind(results, df)
        
    }
}
```

I can then plot the data frame, which nicely shows how the sample means gets closer to the population mean (red dotted line) as the sample size increases:

```
ggplot(results, aes(y = mean, x = sample_size)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_hline(yintercept=mean, linetype="dotted", color = "red", size=3)
```

This is the output (the actual code uses a theme):

[image]

I guess this is straightforward but how can I determine these blue lines expressing the 95% theoretical uncertainty of the sample mean being inside the blue area?

[image]

Is there a formula and does it depend on the knowledge of that the true distribution is normal? I guess it should not, as the sample means will be normally distributed according to the CLT?

Thanks.

PS:

This is the current/final code:

```
mu_ <- 500000
sd_ <- 13000
z_value <- qnorm(.975)
max_sample_size = 500
repeats = 2

results <- NULL
upper_and_lower <- NULL

for (sample_size_ in 3:max_sample_size) {
    
    for (sample_number_ in 1:repeats) {
        
        sample_ <- rnorm(sample_size_, mean=mu_, sd=sd_)
        ci_test <- t.test(sample_, conf.level=0.95)

        df <- data.frame(
            sample_size = sample_size_
            , low_ci = ci_test$conf.int[[1]] 
            , up_ci = ci_test$conf.int[[2]]
            , mean = mean(sample_)
        )

        results <- rbind(results, df)
        
    }
    
    df <- data.frame(
        sample_size = sample_size_
        , upper = mu_ + (z_value * (sd_/sqrt(sample_size_)))
        , lower = mu_ - (z_value * (sd_/sqrt(sample_size_)))
    )
    upper_and_lower <- rbind(upper_and_lower, df)
}

ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=results, aes(y = mean, x = sample_size)) +
    geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = upper, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2) +
    geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = lower, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2)
```

Resulting graph with theoretical 95% uncertainty band:

[image]

Comment: Even though you 'know' $\sigma = 13000$ (from simulation, you're pretending all you know for each t CI is $n, \bar X_n, S_n.$ Then 95% CIs from `t.test` in R will be about $50000 \pm 2 S_n/\sqrt{n}$ for $n > 30.$ For smooth curves, maybe use upper curve $50000 + 2(13000)/\sqrt{n}$ from $n = 30$ to $150.$ [Lower curve with $-.$]

Comment: Unrelated to the question, watch out when you define variables with names used by functions. When I do simulations like this and define mean and standard deviation parameters, I call them “mu” and “s” (should be “sigma”, but I’m content to call it “s”).

Comment: The blues lines that you imagine are not confidence intervals. Confidence intervals are [a function of](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Confidence_intervals) the data/sample mean $\bar{X}$, data/sample deviation $S$ and sample size $n$ and a constant $c$ which depends on the desired confidence level$$\bar{X}_n\pm c \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$Your plot demonstrates how the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ has a variance that scales with $n^{-0.5}$, and you could make boundaries that contain some $x\%$ of the observations, but that is not the same concept as confidence intervals

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus it is the area into which the sample means falls 95% of the time? How can one calculate the confidence interval please? Maybe I could use bootstrapping?

Comment: @cs0815 The confidence interval is $\bar{X}_n\pm c \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. It depends on the sample/observation and you can not plot it as values that are for some given $n$ fixed. (But maybe you are not looking for a confidence interval, and instead you look for a prediction interval or [tolerance interval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval)?)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus thanks - what is c in your formula please?

Comment: @cs0815 $c$ is a parameter that depends on the percentage for the confidence region. It will also depend on $n$. See for more information the link that I referenced in the comment.

Comment: wow 5 up votes but it has been closed!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice experiment.  The blue lines will be at $\mu \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ where $\alpha = 0.05$ and $\alpha \mapsto z_\alpha$ is the upper quantile function of the standard normal and $n$ is `sample_size_`. In this case, this is exact since you are generating from the normal distribution and the sample mean will have the distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. In general, it holds approximately based on the CLT for large $n$.

If you are trying to interpret the CI, that would be a bit different. Putting a CI around each of the points vertically, for each `sample_size_`, roughly 95% of those intervals will cross the dotted red line (you *cover* the true mean $\approx$ 95% of the time, hence the *coverage probability* is 0.95). Since your replication size is small (10), this is not that accurate. Try increasing `sample_number_` to say 1000 to see it better. What you will observe is that although the length of the CIs will be smaller as you increase $n$, still $\approx$ 95% of them keep covering the red line no matter what $n$ is.

---

PS. I am assuming that instead of these two lines:

```
population <- rnorm(10000000, mean=mean, sd=sd)
sample_ <- sample(population, sample_size_)
```

you would do something like this:

```
sample_ <- rnorm(sample_size_, mean=mean, sd=sd)
```

That is, sample from the normal distribution, not a finite population drawn from the normal distribution as you are doing here, although the results will be close in your case (unless your sample size starts approaching 10000000).

Comment: Thanks. Reg PS yes. I just pretended that I have a fixed population.

Comment: Is the standard deviation in your formula the population one? I guess so?

Comment: @cs0815, yes, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the population mean and s.d.

Comment: Thanks. I added some code to my question (see PS). Is the use of qnorm(.975) correct? Thanks!

Comment: @cs0815, no problem. Yes, it looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help